# Setting IF condition to trigger macros in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a condition to trigger macros in excel vba. I defined a named range as "Crosstab 2" and I want to set the IF condition so that if there is the word "G fund" in the  second column third row within the Crosstab 2, it triggers the macros. It is so difficult for me and I am lost..... what must I write after IF in the code to make this work?

The code so far

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Budget- Listening")
    If  Then
        HideFG
    Else
        HideF
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: `Crosstab 2` (with a space) is no valid name for a range. Can you please clarify?

Comment: `If Instr(Range("<range name or address>").Cells(3,2).Value, "G fund") > 0 Then`

Comment: It may help you to review how Events work - see e.g. https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s194/event-handling-vba.htm or Google "Excel VBA events"

Comment: @aucuparia it is a very helpful site, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something along these lines:

```
If ws.Range("Crosstab2").Cells(3, 2) = "G fund" Then
    HidFG
Else
    HideF
End If
```

---

You mentioned you need to run this only for three particular worksheets, e.g: "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3". Copy the above code to these three sheets would work when you adapt the referenced named range.

---

If this is something you need to run on the `Workbook_open()` event, you have multiple options, but since I'd say calling `Worksheet_Change` might not be the best option, maybe try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wshts As Variant: wshts = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
Dim rngs As Variant: rngs = Array("crosstab1", "crosstab2", "crosstab3")

For x = 1 To 3
    If Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).Range(rngs(x - 1)).Cells(3, 2) = "G fund" Then
        HideFG
    Else
        HideF
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wshts As Variant: wshts = Array("Budget", "HR", "Finance")
Dim rngs As Variant: rngs = Array("crosstab1", "crosstab2", "crosstab3")

For x = 1 To 3
    If Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).Range(rngs(x - 1)).Cells(3, 2) = "G fund" Then
        Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).ChartObjects("F").Visible = True
        Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).ChartObjects("FG").Visible = False
    Else
        Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).ChartObjects("F").Visible = False
        Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).ChartObjects("FG").Visible = True
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I think I made it not concrete enough in the original question but it is in line with what you said above. "checking a value in a particular position inside a named range in the sheet". To be specific, in sheet 1 I have crosstab 1. In sheet 2 I have crosstab 2 and in sheet 3, I have crosstab3. And in all the crosstabs, if the word G fund exist, it should trigger HideFG macro. (If not, the Hide F macro.) And the location of the word is the same for all the crosstabs.

Comment: In this case, should I make 3 replicates of the code you suggested above? (by only changing "crosstab2" part into "crosstab1" "crosstab3"..)

Comment: @MooChangPark, but would you still need to trigger the macro on a particular worksheet under the worksheet_change event?

Comment: Yes because I have 7 worksheets in total and the macros are only related to sheet 1, 2 and 3 all with different named ranges. (crosstab1, crosstab2, crossstab3 )

Comment: @MooChangPark, the point I'm trying to make: Do you only want to trigger running the macro from one specific worksheet? Or from these three only? Then sure, replicating it three times is an option :)

Comment: oh I see your point, okay so I want to set it for specific sheet. So it runs the macro as I work on the sheet. Also, I want to set a Workbook_Open() macro so that it checks sheet 1, 2, 3 as the excel opens. :)

Comment: so it the first case, I can replicate the above code into each sheet. I am interested in the second case (Workbook_Open)!

Comment: I'll update the answer with how you could do that. @MooChangPark

Comment: I tried the script (instead of HideFG and Hide F macro I spelled it out) and it says error message "object Required" and highlight the line "ws.ChartObjects("F").Visible = False"....

Comment: I added my script above :)

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is occuring because I changed the sheet name? I changed them to Budget, HR, Finance and tried.

Comment: @moochangPark, notice I did not set a ws object, but simply iterate through the array. Instead of `ws` use  `Sheets(wshts(x - 1))`

Comment: It now works perfect. I am always grateful for your help :)  I hope I was smart as you excel genius! Have a great day

Comment: @MooChangPark, glad it helped, don't forget to upvote answers if they are helpfull to.

Comment: Hello I know its been a while but the Workbook_open macro is having some trouble and it is not running as expected. And I am having a lot of trouble figuring out the reason.... I changed the crosstab name from crosstab 1 crosstab 2 crosstab 3 to crosstab 5 crosstab 7 and crosstab 9.. Is this the reason why?...?

Comment: or maybe... a problem with the IF condition ```If Sheets(wshts(x - 1)).Range(rngs(x - 1))``` ..?

Comment: @MooChangPark, as long as your references are correct, the macro should be fine. Make sure the worksheet names you have in the macro are present in the workbook.

Comment: thanks for coming back. I checked and you are right:) Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Cells(3, 2)) Is Nothing Then
    If Me.Cells(3, 2).Value = "G fund" Then
        HideFG
    Else
        HideF
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Try this code. To explain: Target is the range that has been changed (which triggered the `Worksheet_Change` event). Intersect checks if your specified Range is part of the changed range. If this is the case, then you just have to check if your specified cell's value is equal to your specified input.

Comment: Instead of `ws` you should use `Me` which automatically points to the worksheet the event and `Target` is in. So you don't need to declare `ws` at all.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, what makes you think `ws` would be the same as the one that triggered the event? Not meant to disrespect your comment, just curious because imho the named range could well be a different tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so do I write "cross tab 2" in the Target? Where should I put the named range "crosstab 2"?

Comment: You don't put it "in the Target", since Target is the cell that was changed. If you want to change the cell that is looked at by the macro you need to change Me.Cells(3, 2) to whatever you need.

Comment: @JvdV Just because you cannot intersect `Target` with a range in another sheet it must be the same sheet `Target` is in :) So if `Intersect` is used it is necessary to ensure that `Me` and `ws` is the same, so you can use `Me`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, right. True that, but besides that, what I meant is: OP's named range is probably on another sheet and not on the sheet that triggered the event. Therefor I don't see the point of `Intersect` either since all OP wants to check (imo) is a value in a particular position inside a named range on another sheet. Difference of interpretation I guess :)

Comment: @JvdV Yes, that is another possible interpretation of the original question. That's why I posted it below this answer, to make at least this version consistent and solid. What you describe would be different answer (like the one you posted). • Anyway the OP left too much space for misinterpretation I think.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for the help! excel geniuses :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Me.Range("Crosstab_2")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng.Cells(3, 2)) Is Nothing And rng.Cells(3, 2).Value = "G fund" Then

        'Code

    End If

End Sub
```